# KVM bridge new guest no internet, ping only host and others guest on this host

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7

Had a CentOS KVM host, few Guests on it working well through br0 bridge with real external ip's

Now make new Guest, give it real static ip (as i do on others GUEST), but no internet on it. But new GUEST can ping HOST and other GUEST on this HOST

HOST ifconfig

```
# ifconfig
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 62.*.*.44  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 62.*.*.255
        inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 681705441  bytes 1105019968953 (1.0 TiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 124860  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 193512123  bytes 107459762227 (100.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.19.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.19.255
        inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 167220  bytes 52175150 (49.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 174167  bytes 32975397 (31.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.20.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.20.255
        inet6 fe80::221:91ff:fed6:daa8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:21:91:d6:da:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 145303  bytes 43515865 (41.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 132665  bytes 20911054 (19.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::221:91ff:fed6:daa8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:21:91:d6:da:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2503746  bytes 1017776995 (970.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2471034  bytes 991294789 (945.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp5s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 869448632  bytes 1087851084640 (1013.1 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 342604014  bytes 203755604899 (189.7 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfafe0000-faffffff

enp5s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21206229  bytes 6500554675 (6.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20805805  bytes 6408524379 (5.9 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfaf60000-faf7ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 502370  bytes 78778656 (75.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 502370  bytes 78778656 (75.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:37:be:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:b8:21:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fee2:caae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:e2:ca:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15369361  bytes 45420762336 (42.3 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23668906  bytes 8045283799 (7.4 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe75:4502  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:75:45:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 65372413  bytes 92323003967 (85.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 88528850  bytes 15240358919 (14.1 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe00:761d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:00:76:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20630909  bytes 6375500628 (5.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21037136  bytes 6445910789 (6.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fec3:35e2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:c3:35:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2338278  bytes 970377345 (925.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2359253  bytes 972272478 (927.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fefd:b505  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:fd:b5:05  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 112  bytes 5016 (4.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8480  bytes 614444 (600.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

HOST ip a

```
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br2 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:91:d6:da:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::221:91ff:fed6:daa8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp5s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp5s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br1 state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:91:d6:da:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.254/24 brd 192.168.20.255 scope global br2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::221:91ff:fed6:daa8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet *.*.16.44/24 brd *.*.16.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.5.27/24 brd 192.168.5.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 227543sec preferred_lft 227543sec
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:2e:d8:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.19.254/24 brd 192.168.19.255 scope global br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe2e:d8a9/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b8:21:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: virbr1-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr1 state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b8:21:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:37:be:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:37:be:7d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:75:45:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe75:4502/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: vnet2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:00:76:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe00:761d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: vnet3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br2 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:c3:35:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fec3:35e2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:e2:ca:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fee2:caae/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
48: vnet4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:fd:b5:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fefd:b505/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

HOST route

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         cc4-gw.colocall 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
62.*.*.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 br2
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 br0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1007   0        0 br1
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.19.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br1
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br2
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

HOST brctl show

```
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0025902ed8a8       no              enp5s0f0
                                                        vnet0
                                                        vnet1
                                                        vnet4
br1             8000.0025902ed8a9       no              enp5s0f1
                                                        vnet2
br2             8000.002191d6daa8       no              enp1s4
                                                        vnet3
virbr0          8000.52540037be7d       yes             virbr0-nic
virbr1          8000.525400b82124       yes             virbr1-nic
```

HOST ping to Guest

```
# ping 62.*.*.61
PING 62.*.*.61 (62.*.*.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 62.*.*.61: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.406 ms
64 bytes from 62.*.*.61: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.496 ms
64 bytes from 62.*.*.61: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.371 ms
^C
--- 62.*.*.61 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.371/0.424/0.496/0.055 ms
```

HOST KVM network settings

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:fd:b5:05'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

GUEST ifconfig

```
$ ifconfig
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:fd:b5:05
          inet addr:62.*.*.61  Bcast:62.*.*.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fefd:b505/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11209 errors:0 dropped:5 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:815753 (815.7 KB)  TX bytes:11211 (11.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:742656 (742.6 KB)  TX bytes:742656 (742.6 KB)
```

GUEST ip a

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:fd:b5:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 62.*.*.61/24 brd 62.*.*.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fefd:b505/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

GUEST route

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         62.*.*.2     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```

GUEST ping to HOST

```
$ ping 62.*.*.44
PING 62.*.*.44 (62.*.*.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 62.*.*.44: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.324 ms
64 bytes from 62.*.*.44: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.290 ms
^C
--- 62.*.*.44 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.290/0.307/0.324/0.017 ms
```

GUEST ping to other GUESTs on this HOST

```
$ ping 62.*.*.42
PING 62.*.*.42 (62.*.*.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 62.*.*.42: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.21 ms
64 bytes from 62.*.*.42: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.635 ms
^C
--- 62.*.*.42 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.635/0.927/1.219/0.292 ms
$ ping 62.*.*.17
PING 62.*.*.17 (62.*.*.17) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 62.*.*.17: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.15 ms
64 bytes from 62.*.*.17: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.744 ms
^C
--- 62.*.*.17 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.744/0.947/1.150/0.203 ms
```

GUEST ping to 8.8.8.8

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 62.*.*.61 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 62.*.*.61 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 62.*.*.61 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3016ms pipe 3
```

GUEST /etc/network/interfaces

```
$ tail -n50 /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
        address 62.*.*.61
        netmask 255.255.255.0
#       network 62.*.*.0
        broadcast 62.*.*.255
        gateway 62.*.*.2
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 62.149.2.52 62.149.2.60
```

GUEST iptables

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

i'm confused and do not know, what i need to do (((

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!
I find how to solve this issue:
I just need after making new Guest relad networking.
And all start to work!